# Android popup doesn't shows Action bar

Tags: android, popup, android-actionbar

hi I had created an android app which contains actionbar with 3 tabs.I had created it using a view pager and adapter.It works successfully . But Now I had created a new activity with popup window.I added my activity_main as my contentview. But it doesn't shows action bar tabs.I don't know why.I am new to android . So  please help me, thanks in advance .

here is my code

**MainActivity.java**

```
         public class MainActivity1 extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

       private ViewPager viewPager;
       private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
       private ActionBar actionBar;
       // Tab titles
       private String[] tabs = { "Featured", "Games", "Entertainment" };

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




         viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
         actionBar = getActionBar();
         mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

         viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
         actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
         actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);       

         // Adding Tabs
         for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
          }

         /**
          * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
          viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()   {

             @Override
             public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                 // on changing the page
                 // make respected tab selected
                 actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

               @Override
               public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
              }

               @Override
               public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
              }
           });
       }

       @Override
       public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
       }

       @Override
       public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
           // on tab selected
           // show respected fragment view
          viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
       }

         @Override
       public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }




    }
```

**Here is Code in which I want to popup**

```
      public class Main extends FragmentActivity implements
 ActionBar.TabListener {

       @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.hii);
          Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
               b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                  final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Main.this);
                            // Include dialog.xml file
                           dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                          // Set dialog title
                         dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");

                         // set values for custom dialog components - text, image and button



                         dialog.show();


             }
           });
       }

          @Override
          public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           }

            @Override
                public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          }

           @Override
              public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         }

     }
```

Comment: but its looking in my code..,you want simple dialog in which you have 2 buttons??

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is in your Dialog view. You have to create a dialog which is custom and have to add style with actionbar tab. If you use that style in your dialog box then all those actionbar tabs will come.

I would reccommend instead of using dialog in your b1.setOnclick method create a separate Dialog class which will extend the Dialog class.There you set the content view and make a proper layout with actionbar tabs same as what you have done for your activity.

and inflate the layout from that `dialog class`.**Something like this:--**

```
       b1.setOnClickListener(new View.setOnClickListener){

          new actionbarDialog(MainActivity.this).show();
         }
```

and create a class of `actionbarDialog` which will extend `Dialog class`.

and in onCreate() method of that class write the logic of actionbar that you have written in MainActivity.You will get actionbar tab in Dialog.